# store image installation error in UEC

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, cloud, eucalyptus

to my college final year project we planned to setup the private cloud on the two machines.

I recently installed Ubuntu Enterprise Cloud (UEC) on two of my machines .  I was trying to install the store image through WebUI. I was able to download Ubuntu 10.04 - (i386) image but while installing, it's giving me following error: -

```
Command 'euca-upload-bundle' returned status code 1:
Checking bucket: image-store-1296600766
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/euca-upload-bundle", line 231, in 
    main()
  File "/usr/bin/euca-upload-bundle", line 214, in main
    bucket_instance = ensure_bucket(conn, bucket, canned_acl)
  File "/usr/bin/euca-upload-bundle", line 87, in ensure_bucket
    bucket_instance = connection.get_bucket(bucket)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/boto/s3/connection.py", line 275, in get_bucket
    rs = bucket.get_all_keys(headers, maxkeys=0)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/boto/s3/bucket.py", line 204, in get_all_keys
    headers=headers, query_args=s)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/boto/s3/connection.py", line 342, in make_request
    data, host, auth_path, sender)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/boto/connection.py", line 459, in make_request
    return self._mexe(method, path, data, headers, host, sender)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/boto/connection.py", line 437, in _mexe
    raise e
socket.error: [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

could anyone please help me?

Comment: Note: This should be a comment but I only have 13pts so... To help with this kind of question, it would help to give more information about your setup. Lets start with two basic one: What kind of manual configuration did you do after going through the install process on both machines? What is the content of the eucalyptus.conf file on both machines? This is important since manual configuration is necessary after installation.